# Oracle XMLTYPE: parameter like <123.xml/> not working

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, xmltype

I am using Oracle 11g in which I am passing file name to a function say

```
FUNCTION test(file_name IN XMLTYPE)
```

It accepts file name like `<file1.xml/>` but when I am passing file name as `<123.xml/>` then it is throwing Oracle type exception error. But if I pass file name starting with character again as `<T123.xml/>` then it is working fine.

Please tell me what  need to do to process file name as `<123.xml/>`

Comment: How are you calling the function, and exactly what error do you get? Please add the calling code and the whole error stack to the question. Why are you passing a file name as an `XMLTYPE` anyway, rather than as a string?

Answer (score 2):

`<123.xml/>` is not valid XML: tag names can't start with a digit (or a `.` or `-`). The Wikipedia article on [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) has a good summary on well-formedness. The other two examples you posted are valid XML though, the tag names are well-formed.

Your use-case looks very strange though. If you want to pass a simple filename to that function, why don't you pass a plain string? If you do want to pass a filename encoded in an XML container, something like this would make more sense:

```
<file name="foo.bar"/>
```